# With ffmpeg print onto clipped video hh:mm:ss time *from original* and hh:mm:ss total duration from original

Tags: ffmpeg, video, clipping

I am using arch linux and bash and ffmpeg, all are up to date and the latest versions.

I am clipping a video that is 30 seconds long and wish to clip from 5 secs to 10 seconds to a new file, from the original.

In the bottom right hand corner of the clip I wish to show timestamps from the original video as follows

- in the  5th second "00:00:05/ 00:00:30"
- in the  6th second "00:00:06/ 00:00:30"
  etc
- in the 10th second "00:00:10/ 00:00:30"

This is an apparentley simple question(?) but the syntax of the command is not at all obvious and I am hoping an expert may shed some light on this.

All I have so far for the drawtext part, which does not do what I want as it only counts the elapsed time from t=0 of the **new** clip, whereas **I want it to show the timestamp and total duration of the original clip**

`drawtext` I started with

```
"drawtext=text='%{pts\:gmtime\:0\:%M\\\\\:%S}':fontsize=24:fontcolor=black:x=(w-text_w-10):y=(h-text_h-10)"
```

ffmpeg line with drawtext I have started with

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:05 -i  "$in_file" -filter_complex "drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf:text='sample text':x=10:y=10:fontsize=12:fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5,drawtext=text='%{duration\:hms}':fontsize=12:fontcolor=black:x=(w-text_w-10):y=(h-text_h-10)" -t 5 -c:a copy -c:v libx264 out_file.mp4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.

The ffmpeg presentation timestamp `%{pts}` can only be zeroed and offest, as far as I know, using the `C gmtime` function, with the time set to 1st Jan 2000 in unix time seconds, ie 946684800 seconds, or some other arbitrary time at midnight.

946684800 seconds in UNIX time gives midnight 00:00:00 on 01/01/2000  as a starting point for our calculations, to which we can add our own offset, in this case 5 seconds, as follows.

We don't display the `%d-%m-%Y` portion of the date, so our method is not seen. Works very well. Took a bit of figuring out though.

```
# set file names
in_file="my_video_file.mp4"
out_file="my_video__clipped.mp4"

# set start and end times of the clip to be made
start_time_z="00:00:05"
end_time_z="00:00:10"   

######################################################################
##########                                                  ########## 
##########       get the duration of the                    ##########
##########          input video in hh:mm:ss format          ##########
##########        and convert it to seconds                 ##########
##########                                                  ########## 
######################################################################


total_duration=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration \
  -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$in_file" \
  | awk '{printf("%02d:%02d:%02d\n", ($1/3600), ($1%3600)/60, $1%60)}')

# escape the ":" in the time stamp so that they can be printed by ffmpeg
total_duration="$(echo $total_duration | sed 's@:@\\:@g')"

# display the duration of the original video. Check we have captured it correctly
####    yad --text="\n\n$total_duration\n\n" --button="Submit":0


######################################################################
##########                                                  ########## 
##########       convert the variable                       ##########
##########             $start_time_z   which                ##########
##########                    = 00:00:05                    ##########
##########                                                  ##########
##########    into seconds and add to it unix time for      ##########
##########           00:00:00 on 1st Jan 2000               ##########
##########                                                  ########## 
######################################################################


# convert the clip start time from hh:mm:ss to seconds
start_secs=$(echo "$start_time_z" | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }')

# convert the clip end time from hh:mm:ss to seconds
end_secs=$(echo "$end_time_z" | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }')

# duration of the clip
duration_z=$((end_secs-start_secs))


# Add start time to 946684800 which is 00:00:00 on 1st Jan 2000
total_z=$(echo "$start_secs + 946684800" | bc)
echo $total


######################################################################
##########                                                  ########## 
##########   run the command to create the MAIN  clip       ##########
##########                                                  ########## 
######################################################################


#   below string shows unix time in action
#     by removing the %d-%m-%Y portion we remove the 01-01-2000 part
#       this appears to be the only way to shift pts and add a time shift onto it

# drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf:text='%{pts\:gmtime\:$total_z\:%d-%m-%Y %T} / "$total_duration"':fontsize=$main_clip_font_size:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w-10):y=(h-text_h-10)" \

ffmpeg -ss "$start_time_z" \
    -i "$in_file_name" \
    -filter_complex \
"drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf:text='%{pts\:gmtime\:$total_z\:%T} / "$total_duration"':fontsize=$main_clip_font_size:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w-10):y=(h-text_h-10)" \
       -t  $duration_z \
       -c:a copy -c:v libx264 \
       "$out_file"
```

Comment: Does anyone know of a native ffmpeg command, or other way to add and offset in seconds to ffmpeg's `%{pts}` command without the above workaround?